# 'AddMatVector' is not a member of 'caffe::MemoryDataLayer'

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using the Caffe framework for Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to use caffemodel to classify.

At first,I convert the face database into lmdb format and I have trained the caffemodel(lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel).

Next, I try to use my caffemodel to classify.

I read the code[from google caffe users](http://codepad.org/U4KubL7N) and rewrite some of the content , but I have some errors.

['AddMatVector' is not a member of 'caffe::MemoryDataLayer'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jvJO.png)

I asked in some forums, but I did not receive a reply.

Could anyone help me?

If my description is not clear enough, I will make it clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `AddMatVector` [in the documentation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1MemoryDataLayer.html).

But I can see it [in the source code](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/memory__data__layer_8hpp_source.html) in an `#ifdef USE_OPENCV`. HTH.